# Pytesseract cannot read my text in image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I have some issues with my code, i crop the image using findcountrs and then when i want read whatis inside this crop image, pytessarct dont recognize my text.

I create a while to automatcly increase my threshold value.
Before this the code is ok because i can crop the image where i want.
But now i want read what is inside this image and Tesseract give me a bad results i dont know why.

[image: CropImage]

```py
th=130

while 1:

    th=th+1

    thresh = cv2.threshold(cropped_image, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    print(th)

    dilate2=cv2.dilate(thresh,(5,5))#dilatacao porque sem a dilatacao o pytesseract nao lia direito o texto em questao
    cv2.imshow("ola",dilate2)

    custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 7'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(dilate2, config=custom_config)
    #text = pytesseract.image_to_string(dilate2)
    print(text)

    if "Lava" in text or "Lapa" in text or "Lata" in text:
        break

    if th==255:
        break
```

The best i can:

[image: Console]

Comment: please replace your screenshot of the terminasl with the **text** it contains. you can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use thresh_binary_inv to change all white to black and all other colors to white. Then, use PSM 6 instead of 7. This should work for you. :)